# The model item passed into the dictionary mismatch error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am very new to the mvc3 and trying to implement a simple database web application using entity framework in visual studio 2010. I am following this article :

[msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/gg685467.aspx)

I have done everything written in the post . However I am keep on getting this error :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication3.Models.BlogContext]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'MvcApplication3.Models.BlogContext'.

I am not sure why this error is coming . I followed other post on SO and changed view like this :

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.BlogContext
```

Or

```
@model List<MvcApplication3.Models.BlogContext>
```

None of these are working. Any help will be highly appreciated and boost my learning.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm Actually Julie retrieves all available Blogs from 1 BlogContext like this:

```
using (var db = new BlogContext()) 
{ 
  return View(db.Blogs.ToList()); 
}
```

And sends Blog objects into the View.

In the view you should then have something similiar to :

```
@model List<MvcApplication3.Models.Blog>
```

And **not** items of Type BlogContext. You are not populating the view with a List of complete (Blog)contexts...The context "is" the database, Blogs are items in the Blog table and these are materialized into C# class instances and provided to the view contained in a list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing a `List<BlogContext>` in your controller but your view has `BlogContext` model set. You should define what you need to use and if you need it at all as passing the context to view is really a bad practice (you should not incorporate any logic in your views, that's what you have a controller for).

**In your action method:**

```
var context = new BlogContext();
return View(context);
```

**In your view**

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.BlogContext
```